# My codechef submit is showing wrong result

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve [this codechef problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PCJ18C)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int T;
   scanf("%d", &T);
   assert(T >= 1 && T <= 50);
   while(T--) {
   int n,k;
   long long int a;
   scanf("%d" , &n);
   scanf("%ld" , &a);
   scanf("%d" , &k);
   long int sum = (n-2) * 180;
   long long int d = ((sum - (n*a)) * 2 ) / (n*n - n);
   long long int kthAngle = a + ((k-1)*d);
   printf("%lld 1\n", kthAngle);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I am getting right answers on many of the cases but I am getting wrong answer on codechef submit

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: You must learn to test your own code. If all else fails, it is possible to trick the online judge into revealing the failure case. (It's a neat trick; if you figure it, please don't spoil it for others.)

Comment: Thanks Guys , I got my problem

Comment: Is my solution working for u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d (common_difference) which you are getting can also contain floating point results which you have ignored. You have to consider that too, or process the numerator and denominator parts separately as I have given in the modified solution.

Your solution would therefore fail for cases like:

```
1
7 50 5
```

Output: `3250 21`

Your output: `154 1`

Try this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int T;
   scanf("%d", &T);
   assert(T >= 1 && T <= 50);
   while(T--) {
   int n,k;
   int a;
   scanf("%d" , &n);
   scanf("%d" , &a);
   scanf("%d" , &k);
   int sum = (n-2) * 180;
   int d_numerator = (sum - (n*a)) * 2 ;
   int d_denominator = n * (n-1);

   int kthAngle_num =  a * d_denominator + ((k-1) * d_numerator);
   int kthAngle_den = d_denominator;

   int gcd = __gcd(kthAngle_num, kthAngle_den);

   printf("%d %d\n", kthAngle_num/gcd, kthAngle_den/gcd);
 }
 return 0;
}
```